# Changed ballast on fluorescent light and now lights take 5 minutes or longer to turn on all the way

Tags: fluorescent, ballast

My fluorescent light in my kitchen stopped working so my husband replaced the ballast. Now they come on but so dim you can barely see and take 5 minutes or longer to come on all the way. When I got home from work tonight I waited 35 minutes and they never came on all the way. Please help!!!

Comment: Probably a mismatch of ballast and tube. If you can, [edit] your post to include photos of ballast and markings on tube.

Comment: Rather than change ballast again, you might consider installing LED lighting, instead. LED's are a bit more efficient than fluorescents, provide better color balance, and last longer. There are LED substitutes that fit many types of fluorescent lamps -- in most cases, one removes the ballast, rewires the "tombstone" lamp connectors (easily done), and puts the fixture back in place. Oh... and the LED substitute may cost *less* than a ballast!

Comment: are the tubes working? i would have changed them first.

Comment: Back when I did this for retail, as a simple matter of expediency [our time cost more than the components] we would change tubes & only then, if the startup was slow, also change ballast. Changing ballast without changing tubes just meant you'd have to change them next time you were on site. But, yeah - swap them for LEDs these days. No more ballasts to ever worry about. As a general guide, check what colour the tube ends are, the darker, the more 'worn out'.

Comment: Really not enough info to help. Generally the order is verify nominal ballast voltage matches supply, verify grounding, verify lamp type is compatible with ballast label or instructions, then verify correct wiring and connections. Photos of lamp label and labels on new and old ballast go a long way. (Edit question and use icon with mountains and moon to add photos.)